# Android equivalent of iOS MobileSubstrate-style hooking?

Tags: android, iphone, hook, jailbreak

What is, if any, Android equivalent of MobileSubstrate-style hooking?
I need to understand if it's feasible and doable in reasonable time to hook into digitizer event flow to intercept and do custom processing on gestures/touches.

Clarification: This must be done for ALL applications. Currently I have a tweak that is filtered to UIKit, so it loads everywhere. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it's hard to imagine this being as easy in Android.  Objective-C is just designed to be insecure (I'm sure the language designers wouldn't use that word, but it's really the right word!), so iOS frameworks are trivially easy to hook, once the device is jailbroken.

Comment: I was so focused on the hooking that I completely forgot that Android source is available. Here's a better question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621857/what-process-library-on-android-is-responsible-for-dispatching-touch-events-to-a

Answer (score 2):

Saurik has announced CydiaSubstrate for Android devices supported on versions 2.3 through 4.2, including Kindle Fire, CyanogenMod, and Intel. You need to root your device first in order for it to work. You can read more on [CydiaSubstrate For Android](http://veryrite.com/2013/05/15/cydiasubstrate-for-android/) and download it from [CydiaSubstrate](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/download/com.saurik.substrate.apk) or [GooglePlay Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saurik.substrate).

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To complete the question/answer sequence : there appears be none. Objective-C's dynamic introspection capabilities are the result of smalltalk-like messaging. Java/C don't have that. .Net, on the other hand, comes close with reflection. case closed.