# What process/library on Android is responsible for dispatching touch events to applications?

Tags: android, events, touch, shared-libraries, static-libraries

What process/library on Android is responsible for dispatching touch events to applications?
I was so focused on the hooking that I completely forgot that Android source is available.

Update/Clarification: I want to have my code intercept all touch events for ALL applications in the system, do custom processing on them and forward to original receiver.

Update 2: Assume a rooted device and application for private/internal use only, NOT for mass distribution

Original, badly formulated question: [Android equivalent of iOS MobileSubstrate-style hooking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620873/android-equivalent-of-ios-mobilesubstrate-style-hooking)

Comment: is there a reason you want the actual code? Or are you just looking to grab all incoming touch events before they go anywhere in your app? If so there is a Activity#dispatchTouchEvent ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) ) where you can intercept all touches before they go to the Activity's views...

Comment: @SalilPandit Thank you, see updated problem description

Comment: Person, who down-voted, speak up!

Comment: Wasn't me... I think your question is pretty clear now, but don't really have a direction to send you - sorry...

Comment: @SalilPandit Thanks for the input anyway! I realize that it wasn't you, I just want that "anonymous coward" to come forward :)

Comment: downvotes are not personal attacks, whoever did it probably did so because your (original) question was incredibly vague. No matter why they did it though, calling people cowards will get you no where. People are free to vote how they wish it is not meant to be taken as a personal attack, thus IMO you should refrain from personally attacking them in response. You can ask for clarification without resorting to such things.

Comment: @Tim, I apologize to whoever I might've offended however. please note a ":)" after the phrase. It is just common courtesy to substantiate negative feedback. Besides that, vagueness was not on purpose, but because of lack of knowledge of direction of search. So now everyone that asks a vague question doesn't deserve an answer?

Comment: @YuriyGettya "So now everyone that asks a vague question doesn't deserve an answer?" I never implied this, and I don't believe it to be true. However if you do ask a vague question (for any reason even a legit one, as you did) you may be downvoted for it, but there is no reason to take the downvote personally. And I agree it would've been more helpful had they left a comment.

Comment: @Tim Let me clarify "So now everyone that asks a vague question doesn't deserve an answer?" bit: When down-voted, questions are listed last and gradually fall off the grid, so down-voting essentially denies the person who asked the question a fair hearing.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have my code intercept all touch events for ALL applications in the system, do custom processing on them and forward to original receiver.

This is not possible on stock android (even if your device is rooted). If you wish to do this you'll have to build your own version of the OS that allows for it.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I suspected that, hence in my question I ask "what I need to modify"? Or at least some info to narrow down the search - is it native code, java code, library, process?

Comment: I'm not sure really. [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html) object is capable of sending input events to Activities. That might be a good place to start. [This article](http://cjix.info/blog/misc/internal-input-event-handling-in-the-linux-kernel-and-the-android-userspace/) seems relevant too.